# Async/Await when passing a async function as argument

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I am looking for some best practices. I have cloud functions that trigger on firestore events. For example this test function which triggers on `onCreate`

I also have logic to see if this function already was triggered by the backend (because cloud-functions do not guarantee that the function is only called once, but I need to make sure it only is executed once. (I don't find the source of this anymore but remember that I struggled to understand why this is not guaranteed) - If this changed please let me know

The `shouldProcess` function does some logic (transaction) on the database creating a lock while executing.

I need this for most of my functions which is why I do not want to repeat the try/catch block in every function. I thought I can maybe just pass the code I need to execute as a function parameter to my `process` function but now I am worried that async await does not work here as I expect it to work.

So what I ask is to get some kind of confirmation, that I can do it the way it is shown here

(Of course I tested and it behaves as I think it would. But this is important so I need a reconfirmation)

```
export const asyncTest = functions.firestore
.document('test/{testId}')
.onCreate(async (data, context) => {
    await process(context.eventId, async () => {
        const testRef = admin.firestore().doc(`test/${context.params.testId}`)
        console.debug(`Before await`)
        const test = (await testRef.get()).data()!
        console.debug(test)
    })
})


async function process(eventId: string, processFunction: () => any) {
    try {
        const process = await shouldProcess(eventId)
        if (!process) {
        functions.logger.log("Already processed")
        return null
    }
    await processFunction()
    console.debug(`Finished processing`)
    return markProcessed(eventId)
} catch (err) {
    functions.logger.error(`Execution of ${eventId} failed: ${err}`)
    throw new Error(`Execution failed`);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd change process headline by adding `Promise<any>` to mark the callback is an async function.

`async function process(eventId: string, processFunction: () => Promise<any>) {...}`

Comment: That good. Added it. As we are talking about Promises. Is there any drawback of throwing an error in the try catch or returning null from an async function?

Comment: As I concerned you can use simply return (without any additional thing) and it will return void in this case. I'd use this approach.

Comment: Regarding try catch it depends... - If you want to handle every error for every cases it is OK. - if you want handle most of the errors but you have some exceptions you can throw those in catch again and handle them outside - if you want to handle errros outside don't use try catch inside process instead put process call in try catch block